# No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;ILretrofit2/Converter;)V in class Lretrofit2/ParameterHandler$Body

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I use retrofit `2.6.1` and have the following service:

```
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.*

interface DevicesService {

    @POST("devices/link/")
    fun linkDevice(
        @Body deviceInfo: DeviceInfo
    ): Single<Response<UserDevice>>
```

It raises exception:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;ILretrofit2/Converter;)V in class Lretrofit2/ParameterHandler$Body; or its super classes (declaration of 'retrofit2.ParameterHandler$Body' appears in /data/data/com.myapp.app/app_working/vungle.dex)
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
    at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:126)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;ILretrofit2/Converter;)V in class Lretrofit2/ParameterHandler$Body; or its super classes (declaration of 'retrofit2.ParameterHandler$Body' appears in /data/data/com.my.app/app_working/vungle.dex)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(RequestFactory.java:738)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:306)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:193)
    at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:67)
    at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:26)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:149)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
    at $Proxy3.linkDevice(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.app.data.repository.DevicesRepositoryImpl.linkDevice(DevicesRepository.kt:33)
    at com.myapp.app.interactor.devices.LinkDeviceImpl.exec(LinkDevice.kt:18)
    at com.myapp.app.ui.auth.AuthPresenter.linkDevice(AuthPresenter.kt:109)
    at com.myapp.app.ui.auth.AuthPresenter.access$linkDevice(AuthPresenter.kt:24)
    at com.myapp.app.ui.auth.AuthPresenter$authUser$1.accept(AuthPresenter.kt:149)
    at com.myapp.app.ui.auth.AuthPresenter$authUser$1.accept(AuthPresenter.kt:24)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:62)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
    at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:124)
    ... 7 more
```

As I can see in library sources, the only constructor has this signature:

```
Body(Method method, int p, Converter<T, RequestBody> converter)
```

But my call tries to use `Body(Method method, Converter<T, RequestBody> converter)`

I've inspected dependencies graph, and 2.6.1 is the only used version across all project.

How to fix it?

Comment: Could you please add a few more info, like steps to reproduce and the way you create your Retrofit?